# How to read database (JDBC Request) result into variables in Jmeter

Tags: database, jmeter

I want to read Database result into variables so I can use it for later requests.

1. How can i do it?
2. What if i want to return from database multiple
   columns, or even rows? can loop the returned table same way i can
   with "CSV Data Set Config"?

--edit--

Ok, i found [this solution](http://altentee.com/blogs/2010/dynamic-data-from-jmeter-jdbc-requests/) that uses regular expression to parse the response, but this solution and other like it doesn't work for me, because they require me to change SQL queries so Jmeter could parse them more "easily". I'm using Jmeter to do testing (load testing), and the last thing I want is to maintain 2 different codes, one for "testing" and other for "runtime".

Is there a "specific" JDBC Request solution that enable me to read result into variables using the concept of result-sets and columns?

Answer (score 1):

1. Using The Regular Expression shouldn't affect what your SQL statement looks like. If you need to modify which part of the response you store in variable, use a Beanshell sampler with java code to parse out the response and store into a variable.
2. You can loop through the returned table, by using a FOREACH controller, referencing the variable name in the reg ex.  Make sure in your reg ex, you set the match value to -1 to capture every possible match.